caught SIGWINCH uploading a big file using apache2 and php
I serve a php page using apache2 that allows uploading files
// Check if the file was uploaded
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    // Check for errors in the upload process
    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // Define the target path in the /tmp directory
        $targetPath = '/opt/upload/' . basename($file['name']);

        // Move the uploaded file to the target path
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
            echo "File uploaded successfully to /tmp.";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to move the file to /tmp.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error in file upload: " . $file['error'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No file uploaded.";
}

When I upload a small file of size <8M, it works without a problem. However, when I try uploading a 3.4G file, it ends up in an error

Error in file upload: 1

and in the log tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log one can see
[mpm_prefork:notice] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[mpm_prefork:notice] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

I already configured
post_max_size=20G

in the Loaded Configuration File    /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini.
What's happening? Why can't I upload a big file while it works with small ones?

SIGWINCH is used by apache as part of its shutdown procedure, something is causing apache to restart, and it is unlikely that it is this file upload. There's also no timestamp, and those log events could be completely unrelated to your issue.

@Sammitch I removed timestamps for the clarity

For large file upload, apart from post_max_size, (depending on your configuration) you may also wish to set/amend upload_max_filesize,
max_input_time,
max_execution_time,
max_input_time,
memory_limit

What's wrong with the question? Why did it get -1 without any feedback?

I changed the following additional configuration and it worked, thanks to @Ken Lee for their helpful comment.
upload_max_filesize = 20G
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
memory_limit = 4G


Seriously, does StackOverflow have to be so toxic? I asked chatGPT and it helped me only partially, pointing out post_max_size and www-data permissions, some configuration in .htaccess. There was no other resource and the error was vague. Ken's comment solved the problem pretty easily, was it that hard? What benefit have -1 without feedback and pesky comments brought about? I'm a member for 7 years and I have almost 5k points, not a noob who cannot speak English.
